# plotting tabular data with holoviews

Tags: python, csv, plot, dask, holoviews

I would like to plot data like this

```
 |   |abstime                |hostname   |type   |id |cpu    |mem    |reltime|
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |0  |2017-06-21 02:45:39    |hw03       |ps     |0  |16.0   |0.0    |0:00.08|
 |1  |2017-06-21 02:45:43    |hw03       |ps     |0  |98.0   |0.1    |0:02.23|
 |2  |2017-06-21 02:45:48    |hw03       |ps     |0  |1591.0 |0.1    |0:21.09|
 |3  |2017-06-21 02:45:52    |hw03       |ps     |0  |0.0    |0.1    |0:38.35|
 |4  |2017-06-21 02:45:57    |hw03       |ps     |0  |0.0    |0.1    |1:01.41|
```

using Holoviews Python package.

## I'm trying to create multiple widgets like this:

```
                                               DROPDOWN (hostname)
LINE PLOTS ( abstime vs cpu )                  DROPDOWN (type)
colored by id
```

```
                                               DROPDOWN (hostname)
LINE PLOT ( abstime vs cpu )                   DROPDOWN (type)
                                               DROPDOWN (id)
```

```
LINE PLOT ( abstime vs cpu )                   DROPDOWN (hostname)
colored by type
```

I think ideally would be to use something like `hv.Table` and then slice and dice it using `.to.curve` and other techniques of Holoviews.

I'm trying to follow examples and tutorials - but none of them has repetitions in columns so I'm confuse how to group, what should be my kdims, vdims and cdims...

## For Ex.:

```
table=hv.Table(df,kdims=['abstime','reltime','hostname','type','id'],vdims=['cpu','mem'])

print(table)
#:Table   [abstime,reltime,hostname,type,id]   (cpu,mem)

table[None,None,{'hw03'},{'ps'},None].to.curve('abstime','cpu')
```

this gives me an error at the last call:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'itertuple'
```

Any related examples highly appreciated!

BTW, my table `df` is Dask Dataframe (many CSV files) so I rely on delayed computing if that matters...

Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be a simple typo in HoloViews, which I've made a fix for here: https://github.com/ioam/holoviews/pull/1593

The fix will be available in the next release, which is HoloViews 1.8 and will be available later today in the 1.8dev3 release installable using ``conda install -c ioam/label/dev holoviews``.

Answer (score 0):

To get the dropdown I expanded your dataset to include records with another hostname:

```
 |abstime            |hostname|type|id|cpu   |mem| reltime
0| 2017-06-2102:45:39|hw03    |ps  |0 |16.0  |0.0| 0:00.08
1| 2017-06-2102:45:43|hw03    |ps  |0 |98.0  |0.1| 0:02.23
2| 2017-06-2102:45:48|hw03    |ps  |0 |1591.0|0.1| 0:21.09
3| 2017-06-2102:45:52|hw03    |ps  |0 |0.0   |0.1| 0:38.35
4| 2017-06-2102:45:57|hw04    |ps  |0 |0.0   |0.1| 1:01.41
5| 2017-06-2102:45:39|hw04    |ps  |0 |16.0  |0.0| 0:00.08
6| 2017-06-2102:45:43|hw04    |ps  |0 |98.0  |0.1| 0:02.23
7| 2017-06-2102:45:48|hw04    |ps  |0 |1591.0|0.1| 0:21.09
8| 2017-06-2102:45:52|hw04    |ps  |0 |0.0   |0.1| 0:38.35
9| 2017-06-2102:45:57|hw04    |ps  |0 |0.0   |0.1| 1:01.41
```

I'm using Pandas rather than dask but the principle is the same:

```
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')
d=pd.read_csv('so.csv')
# Create a holoviews dataset from any of a number of data structures.
ds=hv.Dataset(d)
display(ds.data)
#Now create a table from just the columns that we want. Otherwise
#You will get more dropdowns than you might want in the holomap.   
tb=hv.Table(ds,kdims=['abstime','hostname','type'],vdims='cpu')
display(tb)
#This is a dimensioned element.
hv.HoloMap(tb.to.curve(kdims=['abstime'],vdims='cpu'))
```

That will give you a dropdown for the hostname and will display the curve of abstime versus cpu.  If you data had more than one type there would be a second dropdown widget as well.